# How do I center these images on the page?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a beginner project as I am new into web dev/design and am trying to center these images. I've included a link with screenshots of my code and the webpage in Firefox.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/g6zvH#2]

Comment: Images are inline level elements. They treat as text, links, ... Simply use `text-align: center;` on their container element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What normally works if your images are not wrapped in another div.

```
.grid {
    margin:0 auto; // Shortcut for margin-left:auto and margin-right: auto
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

What it does is align all of the contents to the center of the div.

However since all of your images are wrapped in another element they will not center depending on your styling of container elements.

What i would say is the best way to approach your issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/c0oku4zu/2/

Comment: I have them wrapped in that div to crop the images down to the same size/shape, but I just added text-align:center; within .grid like you have above and it centered perfectly.

Comment: It works most of the time but once in awhile depending on what your design is you might have to make a few small changes. I updated my post with a different way to do it with a bit less code